# Eigenvectors basis and orthonormal basis for of linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the following true:

Let $V$ be an inner product space, and $T:V\to V $ is a linear transformation, suppose that we have eigenvectors basis of $T$. Thus, there exist orthonormal eigenvectors basis of $T$.

I suspect that this statement true iff $T$ is self adjoint.

Comment: You suspicion is right. Also, $T$ is represented by symmetric matrix in the standard basis...

Comment: Hint: Gram-Schmidt Process proves *any* basis in an inner product linear space can be orthonormalized...

Comment: My apologies, but it seems that I can'n combine these two above comments, and make from them some counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I see that *now* (it must be Daved and I posted at the same time): the basis (of eigenvectors) you talk about can be orthonormalized, yet it seems to be you would want this new orthonormal basis to *still* be formed by eigenvectors of $\,T\,$ ? Then yes, the operator has to be self-adjoint to assure this.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is not self-adjoint, there exist $v,w\ne 0$ such that
$$\langle Tv,w\rangle\ne \langle v,Tw\rangle\,.$$
Then there must be a pair $b_i,b_j$ of the given eigen-basis which also satisfies this inequality (since if all pairs would give equality, then it would hold for all vectors as well, by linearity).

This means $\lambda_i\,\langle b_i,b_j\rangle \ne \bar\lambda_j\,\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$. In particular, $b_i\not\perp b_j$ follows.

On the other hand, if $T$ is self-adjoint, the same argument, $\lambda_i\,\langle b_i,b_j\rangle = \bar\lambda_j\,\langle b_i,b_j\rangle$ shows that its eigenvalues must be real, and that the eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.